# Is there a function that can make a line in a textbox be highlighted and displayed when i click on a button?

Tags: excel, vba

[image]
When i search for something it will be highlighted in the listbox. I want it to scroll down automatically and display the highlighted information on the screen when the find button is clicked.

```
myindex = 0

Set itmx = ListView2.FindItem(Trim(TextBox_Reason.Text), lvwText, lvwPartial)
    If itmx Is Nothing Then
        If TextBox_Reason.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox "Please enter a Reason", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        Else
        result = MsgBox("Reason not found !, Add new Reason ", vbYesNo, "Reason Status")
        If result = vbYes Then
            CommandButton_Add_Click
        End If
        Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        ListView2.ListItems(itmx.Index).Selected = True
        ListView2.SetFocus
    End If

myindex = 0


Set itmx = ListView2.FindItem(Trim(TextBox_Reason.Text), lvwText, lvwPartial)
    If itmx Is Nothing Then
        If TextBox_Reason.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox "Please enter a Reason", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        Else
        result = MsgBox("Reason not found !, Add new Reason ", vbYesNo, "Reason Status")
        If result = vbYes Then
            CommandButton_Add_Click
        End If
        Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        ListView2.ListItems(itmx.Index).Selected = True
        ListView2.SetFocus
    End If
```

Comment: Yes, you can format a pre-determined string within a string using Characters()

Comment: I watched a few videos on that function and i don't think its what i'm looking for.                            ListView2.ListItems(itmx.Index).Selected = True
        ListView2.SetFocus                                                                                                             I think it should be another line under this saying something like display focus.

Comment: You can try:  http://vbcity.com/forums/t/89921.aspx

Comment: ...or just `ListView2.ListItems(itmx.Index).EnsureVisible`